# SQL Server 2012 Data-Tier Application Template for Visual Studio?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2012, data-tier-applications

Is there a SQL Server 2012 Data-tier Application template for VS 2010?  The version of the template I am using will only allow SQL Server 2008R2.

If I open the Management Console in SQL Server 2012 and extract a DAC package, that works and the package is created.  However, VS will not allow me to import the pakcage, it gives the following error: "The file you have specified is not a valid Data-tier Application file. Specify a valid file."

Comment: Take a look here: http://boardreader.com/thread/How_to_get_the_VS2010_project_templates_ri0o__dddea11d-12e7-46c2-8388-e95a94e7825e.html

Comment: Tried the suggestion in your link, it opens VS, but the only template available is for 2008 R2 only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data-tier application framework is part of the [Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Feature Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29065).

It's also available as a standalone download from that page. Scroll down to *Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 Data-Tier Application Framework*.